# Kivy Audio наложение трека вместо последовательного воспроизведения

Tags: python, аудио, kivy

запустить/остановить аудио по кнопкам могу, но при запуске другого трека он накладывается, а не становится вместо предыдущего.

```
    from kivy._event import EventDispatcher
    from kivy.app import App
    from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader
    from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
    from kivy.uix.button import Button


    class MyApp(App, EventDispatcher):
        def build(self):
            bl = BoxLayout(orientation='horizontal')
            bl.add_widget(Button(text='1-ая песня',
                                 on_press=self.btn_first))
            bl.add_widget(Button(text='2-ая песня',
                                 on_press=self.btn_second))
            return bl

        def btn_first(self, instance):
            sound = SoundLoader.load(
                '01. Feed The Machine.mp3')
            sound.play()

        def btn_second(self, instance):
            sound = SoundLoader.load(
                '02. Coin For The Ferryman.mp3')
            sound.play()


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stackoverflow  на русском! Хочу заметить, что значение слова "налаживается" не такое, в каком Вы использовали его здесь. Приведите свой код, пожалуйста.

Comment: Также краткое описание ("название") вопроса следует составлять так, чтобы оно выражало смысл вопроса и, по крайней мере, соответствовало тому, о чём Вы хотите спросить.

Comment: Чтобы аудио "становилось вместо предыдущего" предыдущее аудио нужно остановить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы аудио "становилось вместо предыдущего" предыдущее аудио нужно остановить. Как-то так:

```
class MyApp(App, EventDispatcher):
    sound = SoundLoader.load('dummy.mp3')

    def build(self):
        bl = BoxLayout(orientation='horizontal')
        bl.add_widget(Button(text='1-ая песня',
                             on_press=self.btn_first))
        bl.add_widget(Button(text='2-ая песня',
                             on_press=self.btn_second))
        return bl

    def btn_first(self, instance):
        if self.sound.state == "play":
            self.sound.stop()
        self.sound.load('01. Feed The Machine.mp3')
        self.sound.play()

    def btn_second(self, instance):
        if self.sound.state == "play":
            self.sound.stop()
        self.sound.load('02. Coin For The Ferryman.mp3')
        self.sound.play()
```

Comment: Нет, в другой функции это всё должно делаться, объект sound не известен, мы его же не передаем.

Comment: Да, точно. Поэтому его нужно сделать глобальным.

Comment: Подправил. Примерно так. Но код на работоспособность не проверял, возможны ошибки. Ну и строчку ``self.sound = SoundLoader.load('dummy.mp3')`` надо бы изменить, чтобы не загружать файл, а просто создать пустой объект.

Comment: @Эникейщик self.sound = None - это пустой объект?